# Adapter not recognizing my java class

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, rhino, worklight-adapters

I want to invoke a java class in an adapter. I have created a class called com.wl.poc.LdapUserCreator and successfully got it working in WL server (invoked it from another context)

In my adapter's code I put this :

```
var url = WL.Server.configuration['com.wl.poc.ldap.providerUrl'];
var uidExpression =  WL.Server.configuration['com.wl.poc.ldap.uidExpression'];
var base = WL.Server.configuration['com.wl.poc.ldap.ldapSearchBase'];
var managerDn = WL.Server.configuration['com.wl.poc.ldap.managerDn'];
var managerPwd = WL.Server.configuration['com.wl.poc.ldap.managerPwd'];


var service =wl.poc.LdapUserCreator.getServiceInstance( url,  uidExpression,  base,  managerDn,  managerPwd);
```

I have this error

> ReferenceError: "wl" is not defined (.../IntegrationAdapter-impl.js#373)

Another question : 
If is it possible to have an instance of service class in the adapter (which is a java instance) and call it after  like this (Haven't yet tried it) ?

```
var service =wl.poc.LdapUserCreator.getServiceInstance( url,  uidExpression,  base,  managerDn,  managerPwd);
service.addNewUser(...) ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Got it. Package name does not start with **com** read the Worklight's documentation about that on Adapter section.